# Show two matrices are not similar

Tags: matrices, similar-matrices

I have two matrices

\begin{bmatrix}2&1&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}

and

\begin{bmatrix}2&1&0\\0&2&1\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}

I need to show they are not similar. However, they have the same determinant, rank, nullity and eigenvalues. They are also both invertible.

Comment: Minimal polynomials?

Comment: Call them $A$ and $B$. Compare $(A-2I)^2$ and $(B-2I)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

If the matrices were similar, that means that both of them would have the same amount of independent eigenvectors, since if $Av=\lambda v$ then:
$$BP^{-1}v=P^{-1}APP^{-1}v=P^{-1}Av=\lambda P^{-1}v$$
But if you look at $A-2I$ in your case, one has rank $1$ while the other has rank $2$, which means the first matrix has only $1$ eigenvector for $\lambda=2$ and the secone one has $2$ indepentent eigenvectors for $\lambda=2$. Hence, they cannot be similar.